# Python Selenium: clicking a "visible" element using Selenium gives me an "element not visible" error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to test against this website. (https://www.phptravels.net/), and I want to test its Login feature. There is a "My Account" link, which needs to be clicked first to show the drop down of the Login and Sign up button. The HTML code is like this:

```
<li id="li_myaccount" class="">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle go-text-right" aria-expanded="false"><span class="ink animate" style="height: 137px; width: 137px; top: -10.7969px; left: -28.7344px;"></span><i class="icon_set_1_icon-70 go-right"></i> My Account <b class="lightcaret mt-2 go-left"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="go-text-right" href="https://www.phptravels.net/login"> Login</a></li>
        <li><a class="go-text-right" href="https://www.phptravels.net/register">  Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

When I try to click the "My Account" button, it throws an error msg saying "element not visible". I am confused because apparently this button is visible all the time. Here is the code:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='li_myaccount']/a")
elem.click()
```

What is wrong with my code? Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the xpath to this one:

```
(//*[@id='li_myaccount']/a)[2]
```

If you look at the source, there are actually 2 elements matching this locator - an `<a>` tag in some modal that's currently hidden, and the one you are trying to address; thus your issue, the method returns the first one, which is not the desired.

This xpath will return the 2nd element (`[2]`) from the set of responses (the `()` surrounding the looked-for value).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to interact with the My Account Link, which is shown in the right part of the navigation bar on the page (https://www.phptravels.net/). Using the locator `//*[@id='li_myaccount']/a` when I try to click the Link, using the Webdriver, I get the below error:

```sh
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
```

When I explored the html using Chrome's console and searched the element using the locator `//*[@id='li_myaccount']/a`, the My Account Link, which you want to click doesn't get highlighted.

Therefore further exploration led me to choose the locator `//*[contains(@class,'navbar-nav navbar-right')]//*[@id='li_myaccount']/a` which highlights the My Account Link.

Then I used the new locator to click My Account link, using the Webdriver and it works !
If you notice carefully, I just added preceding path in the locator that you shared to uniquely identify the My Account Link.

[image: Click My Account Link]